# Calling OpenGL functions in SDL project causing it to not compile under OSX

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl, sdl-2

I am using SDL2 (latest OSX binaries), C++ and OpenGL in Xcode 8.3.2. The project builds nicely if I am just calling SDL2 functions from the code. However when I include any OpenGL function call in the code it fails to compile. I have already included `<OpenGL/gl3.h>` in the file header. But I am getting the following error during compilation whenever I invoke any OpenGL method in the code:

[image]
Relevant code:

in Display.h:

```
#ifndef Display_h
#define Display_h

#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>
...
```

in Display.cpp:

```
void Display::Clear(float r, float g, float b, float a)
{
   glClearColor(r,g,b,a);
}
```

I am running OSX 10.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem's been solved. I needed to add the OpenGL framework under "Build Phases" > "Link Binary With Libraries" of the project. I already did that for SDL2. But didn't know that I need to do the same for OpenGL too.

Comment: Yes, of course you have to. In fact it's actually a pretty bad thing if recursive dependencies are pulled in implicitly behind the scenes; it might be more convenient. But in the explicit case error messages (also at runtime) are much easier to comprehend, because as a developer you know specifically what's in your program and what not.